# UIImageView transform distortion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

I have searched the web over the last 2 days for a solution to this to no avail.

To demonstrate, I have a simple tabbed application with an image and a button. If I perform a simple rotation using:

```
- (IBAction)rotate:(id)sender {

_imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_angle);

_angle +=0.1;
}
```

When I switch the tab to the 2nd viewcontroller and back to the 1st Viewcontroller, my image appears distorted. Any ideas why?

As I wait for a better/more elegant answer, I have disabled Autolayout on my storyboard file as an intermediate solution to make this work.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the distortion, before and after please?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a test with a demo (a tabViewController with three subViewControllers,each subViewController wraped in a independent navigationController), it seem all right.

Please paste in the code here for further investigation.